# How to retrieve an associated property in a struts form

Tags: java, jsp, struts-1

I'm trying to familiarize with Struts 1 because it is still being used in our current project. Upon creating a simple data entry application, I encountered an exception that says;

> javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Exception thrown by getter for
>   property: "city" of bean: "studentForm"

1. Is there a way for the Struts HTML form to access the Address fields; City and Province?
2. Does the Struts HTML form property tag accepts only string data types?

Person.class

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class Person implements Serializable {

    static SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("M/dd/yyyy");

    @Column(name = "first_name", nullable = false, updatable = true, insertable = true)
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name", nullable = false, updatable = true, insertable = true)
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "date_of_birth", nullable = false, updatable = true, insertable = true)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private String dateOfBirth;

    @Embedded
    private Address address;

public Address getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(Address address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
```

Address class

```
@Embeddable
public class Address {

    @Column(name = "city", nullable = false, updatable = true, insertable = true)
    private String city;

    @Column(name = "province", nullable = false, updatable = true, insertable = true)
    private String province;

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city.toUpperCase();
    }

    public String getProvince() {
        return province;
    }

    public void setProvince(String province) {
        this.province = province.toUpperCase();
    }
```

Student Action form

```
public class StudentForm extends ActionForm {

    private StudentBean student = new StudentBean();
    private Address address = new Address();

public Address getAddress() {
        return student.getAddress();
    }

    public void setAddress(Address address) {
        this.student.setAddress(address);
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return student.getAddress().getCity();
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.student.getAddress().setCity(city);
    }

    public String getProvince() {
        return student.getAddress().getProvince();
    }

    public void setProvince(String province) {
        this.student.getAddress().setProvince(province);
    }
```

Struts 1 HTML form

```
<html:form action="RegisterStudent.do">

        <label for="firstName">First Name: </label>
        <html:text name="studentForm" property="firstName" />
        <br>
        <label for="lastName">Last Name: </label>
        <html:text name="studentForm" property="lastName" />
        <br>
        <label for="dateOfBirth">Date of Birth(mm/dd/yyyy): </label>
        <html:text name="studentForm" property="dateOfBirth" />
        <br>
        <label for="city">City: </label>
        <html:text name="studentForm" property="city" />
        <br>
        <label for="province">Province: </label>
        <html:text name="studentForm" property="province" />
        <br>
        <label for="department">School Department: </label>
        <html:text name="studentForm" property="department" />
        <br>
        <html:submit>Register</html:submit>

    </html:form>
```

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Is there a way for the Struts HTML form to access the Address fields; City and Province?

Struts can populate request parameters to nested objects of `ActionForm`. If `StudentBean` is extends `Person` class. You can modify the page to:

```
<html:form action="RegisterStudent.do">
    <label for="firstName">First Name: </label>
    <html:text name="studentForm" property="student.firstName" />
    <br>
    <label for="lastName">Last Name: </label>
    <html:text name="studentForm" property="student.lastName" />
    <br>
    <label for="dateOfBirth">Date of Birth(mm/dd/yyyy): </label>
    <html:text name="studentForm" property="dateOfBirth" />
    <br>
    <label for="city">City: </label>
    <html:text name="studentForm" property="student.address.city" />
    <br>
    <label for="province">Province: </label>
    <html:text name="studentForm" property="student.address.province" />
    <br>
    <label for="department">School Department: </label>
    <html:text name="studentForm" property="department" />
    <br>
    <html:submit>Register</html:submit>
</html:form>
```

> 2. Does the Struts HTML form property tag accepts only string data types?

You can specify other types in `ActionForm`, the conversion can be customised. For Struts1, read [this FAQ](http://wiki.apache.org/commons/BeanUtils/FAQ).
For Struts2, please refer [Type Conversion](https://struts.apache.org/docs/type-conversion.html)